# Push files to SVN

Tags: svn, terminal, linux-mint

I am using Linux Mint 18.1. I checked out a Laravel remote repository using `svn checkout` command from terminal.  I worked on that repository and now I would like to push files to that remote repository. How can I do that?

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.commit

Answer (score 2):

This operation is called **commit changes**. You should run [`svn commit`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn-book.html#svn.tour.cycle.commit) to send or publish your changes to the remote repository.